# 'each felt a breast' vs. 'each felt the breast' (with genial instinct filled)

Tags: articles, poetry

From "[A Tale. June 1793](http://allpoetry.com/A-Tale.-June-1793)" by William Cowper:

> In Scotland's realm forlorn and bare
>   The history chanced of late,--
>   This history of a wedded pair,
>   A chaffinch and his mate,.
>
> The spring drew near, each felt **a** breast
>   With genial instinct filled;
>   They paired, and would have built a nest,
>   But found not where to build.

Each [chaffinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_chaffinch) has only one breast. Would it be okay to say "each felt **the** breast with genial instinct filled"?

Comment: If you use **the**, it means that you know which breast you're talking about.

Comment: No. They're a wedded pair, he and she.  There's no neutral pronoun, but the indefinite article can serve that purpose: each bird feels its breast to be full of genial instinct.  Consider: "Standing so long at attention wearing 100-pound packs, each soldier had *an* aching back".

Comment: *Its* is not appropriate given the anthropomorphic "wedded pair".

Comment: @TRomano - I don't fully understand the point about "no neutral pronoun".  I understand that we can't use **his** or **her**. But why can't **the** serve instead of **a**? - How about "Standing so long at attention wearing a 100-pound pack, each soldier felt like **the** back was full of pain."? (I admit it feels strange.. With the birds, it felt less strange)

Comment: If we're not able to use a possessive (as here we cannot because of the gender issues raised by "wedded pair") then we have to choose between the indefinite or the definite article, and idiomatically, when speaking of a group undergoing a similar feeling, we tend to abstract with the indefinite article rather than particularize with the definite.  "The honeymooners, eating the famous chili which today of all days had accidentally been overspiced with scotch bonnet peppers, felt a stomach on fire."  "a stomach on fire" refers (abstractly) to the sensation felt, whereas "the stomach on fire" ...

Comment: ... would be an ellipsis of "the stomach (to be) on fire".  But since there's more than one stomach involved, we wouldn't say "the".

Comment: also **each** makes **their** impossible (in strict mode) so there's a number issue too.

Comment: Why does **each** make **their** impossible? ...**each** felt **their** *(own)* breast filled with genial instinct? Isn't **each to their own** more **gender-inclusive**?

Comment: @Peter: You'll notice that my comment was qualified with "(in strict mode)". Coleridge discusses the grammatical issue of a gender-agnostic pronoun for a *person* in the early 1800s, and he does not opt for "they/their" but for "it/its". I don't believe **their** would have been accepted as grammatical by Cowper in 1793 either, since in his day it was rejected by grammarians for such use, as a plural form.

Comment: *The* would be okay or "allowable", at least grammatically. (I will try to find examples.) As far as style, meter, rhythm, poetry, etc, it may not be the best choice. *Each* could feel either *the* breast or *a* breast (as well *its* breast). The least specific of those is *a* and for whatever reason works great there. It also helps that the paired line is 'built **a** nest'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "the" would imply that there was only one breast and they were both feeling the same one.

You could replace "a" with "its" though:

```
The spring drew near, each felt its breast
With genial instinct filled;
```

This is grammatically correct, but as I read the original, I get the feeling that the use of "a" makes the breast more of a independent entity which drives the bird's behaviour.  I think that's why "a" has been used.